# wsdl2Java Incorrect : Two <port> elements with the same name exception

Tags: java, wsdl, wsdl2java

I am trying to WSDL2Java tool to generate java classes from this wsdl.

http://sms2.cdyne.com/sms.svc?wsdl

However, I am getting an exception.

java.io.IOException: Two  elements with the same name "sms2SOAPbasicHttpBinding" found

I verified that all port names are unique within the wsdl. It will be greatly appreciated if someone enlightens me to what is happening here.

Comment: Try SoapUI first to check if the above wsdl actually works. Once that is done you can use Axis2 to generate your java code.

Comment: With SoapUI the WSDL works fine. I think I do have inkling of why the issue occurs - likely due to multiple bindings. But I am not sure why. I was hoping that I could resolve the issue using AXIS instead of AXIS2.

Comment: You can give that a try.

Comment: This issue is now solved, using apache cxf.